# How to handle meeting schedules with many supervisors?

Tags: phd, graduate-school, advisor, supervision, lab-meeting

I am a third year PhD student co-supervised by supervisors A and B.
I am starting a visiting researcher exchange in another university for three months, where I will be supervised by C.

I agreed with C on weekly meetings, which makes sense to me. But I know B wants to join (B was clearly upset several time because he missed meetings with C), and then it is weird to exclude A. However, I really don't want to have all my meetings with all three senior people as I know it is not going to be productive for me.

How should I manage my meeting schedule? I would be fine meeting A and B only once a month, but I'm afraid it would be badly received, especially by B.

Answer (score 3):

We absolutely cannot answer what your meeting schedule should be like!

Your relationship with your supervisors is like any other relationship. For it to succeed you need to: communicate, communicate, communicate.

In this case, discuss your expectations and their expectations and find a solution that works for everyone. Don't be shy to express your needs and preferences. Good luck!